# CoreData Many-To-Many relationship with attributes. Insert, Delete, Request

Tags: core-data, swift

I have the following issue with CoreData, and I cannot find any tutorial dealing with it. The problem is that I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities: Station and Program. A given station can have many programs assigned, and a given program can be assigned to many stations. In the middle, a time is associated to the relationship. Thus, the tuple station-program has an attribute time associated. After looking around, I've seen that the best solution is to create an intermediate entity, which I've called TimeStationProgram:

**Station <-->> TimeStationProgram <<--> Program**

I can create instances of Station and Program normally. However, I don't know how to create a specific instance of the new entity TimeStationProgram. I don't know either how to delete or recover specific data, either. Thank you!

Code in Objective-C is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your ERD a little adding an additional relationship between Station and Program (assuming you would want to do things like: given a station, show me all the programs, and vice versa). Also, I changed the relationship between station/program and TimeStationProgram to be a 1-to-1 as you will only ever have 1 time relationship between a single station and a single program (i.e. you won't have multiple times that a program will be available on the same station)

[image]

Now, each of the items mentioned above is an 'object'. Therefore you need to think about objects as you begin to create and associate them together.

```
// Create the instances

// create a Station
 Station *dbEntityStation = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Station"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:[self.managedObjectContext]];

// create a Program
 Program *dbEntityProgram = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Program"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:[self.managedObjectContext]];

// create a TimeStationProgram
 TimeStationProgram *dbEntityTSP = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeStationProgram"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:[self.managedObjectContext]];

// Handle the relationships

// Map Station to TimeStationProgram
dbEntityStation = dbEntityTSP;

// Map Program to TimeStationProgram
dbEntityProgram = dbEntityTSP; // note same TSP instance for both Station & Program

// Map Station to Program
[dbEntityStation addProgramsObject:dbEntityProgram]
// if you wanted to add multiple Program(s) to a Station you would need to load them into a set then add as follows
// NSMutableSet *programs = [NSMutableSet new];
// <load up the set with Program(s)
// [dbEntityStation addPrograms:programs];
```

The key takeaway is that you need to create each of the 3 objects mentioned. You need to identify which objects should be associated, then you need to collect those objects and map them to each other through their relationships. The example I use above is simplistic and I expect your program will be more complex. Especially the part that deals with fetching existing Program(s) and associating them to Stations.

Note: This isn't code-complete, but it should paint the picture.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's a good point to change the relationship between Station/Program and TimeStationProgram to be a 1-to-1. I'll try to continue coding from this ERD. Thanks!!!

Comment: I definitely need a to-many relationship:
Station <-->> TimeStationProgram <<--> Program

In this case, I still don't know how to insert data in case of objects of the TimeStationProgram entity. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Check out the header files for your entities, in particular TimeStationProgram. You should see a few helper methods defined at the bottom of the file (see my comments above). These are used to add a single object or a 'set' of objects to the relationship. See my solution above and apply what I said about Program(s)). The only thing that really changes if you use to-many is you are dealing with 'sets'.

Comment: e.g. // Map TimeStationProgram to Station as follows: 
[dbEntityTimeStationProgram addSationsObject:dbEntityStation]